# I have files encoded with PHP 7.2 + ionCube 10.3

Tags: classloader, loader, bootloader, autoload, ioncube

I have files encoded with PHP 7.2 + ionCube 10.3
I want to decrypt these files, is there a way online?
These files start with these symbols

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Paid decoder https://easytoyou.eu/decoders